# Jmeter error while running webdriver sampler script to remote machine

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, load-testing, distributed-testing

My webdriver sampler code is below:

```
var pkg = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium); //WebDriver classes
var support_ui = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait); //WebDriver classes
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
var wait = new support_ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 5000);
WDS.browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
WDS.browser.get('http://interview.erainfotechbd.com:5003/')
WDS.log.info("chat bot opended")
//var name= WDS.args[0]
//var number= WDS.args[1]
WDS.log.info("names are :" +WDS.args[0])
WDS.log.info("numbers are :" +WDS.args[1])
var wait=new support_ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 5)
WDS.browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
var userName = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath('//input[@name="nickname"]'))
userName.click(); //clicks search field
userName.sendKeys(WDS.args[0]) //types word "blazemeter" in field//saves search field into searchField
var mobileNumber = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath('//input[@name="mobile"]'))
mobileNumber.click(); //clicks search field
mobileNumber.sendKeys(WDS.args[1]) //types word "blazemeter" in field//saves search field into searchField
var loginButton = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath('//button[@id="Enter"]'))
loginButton.click(); //clicks login button
var wait=new support_ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 5)
var selectInterview= WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath('//form[@id="myFormInt"]/input[1]'))
selectInterview.click()
var wait=new support_ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 20)
//timeouts.pageLoadTimeout(600, timeUnit.TimeUnit.SECONDS)
var returnedAnswer=WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath('//input[@class="form-control"]')).getText()
var enterValidNumber= WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath('//input[@class="form-control"]'))
enterValidNumber.sendKeys('01676912613')
var sendMessagebutton= WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath('//button[@id="sendMessage"]'))
sendMessagebutton.click()
var wait=new support_ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 20)
//timeouts.pageLoadTimeout(600, timeUnit.TimeUnit.SECONDS)
WDS.vars.put('renderTime', renderTime.toString())
WDS.sampleResult.getLatency()
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

I have configured my My Master jmeter server as below :

```
server.rmi.ssl.disable=true
remote_hosts=127.0.0.1 , 10.11.200.203
```

After running my script it is giving following exception to slave machine(10.11.200.203)

```
RemoteListenerWrapper: testStarted(host) on 10.11.200.203
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 10.0.75.1; nested exception is:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21.testStarted(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.RemoteListenerWrapper.testStarted(RemoteListenerWrapper.java:79) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfStart(StandardJMeterEngine.java:208) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:381) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_231]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
... 11 more
2020-02-09 09:31:37,277 ERROR o.a.j.s.RemoteListenerWrapper: testStarted(host) on 10.11.200.203
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 10.0.75.1; nested exception is:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21.testStarted(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.RemoteListenerWrapper.testStarted(RemoteListenerWrapper.java:79) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfStart(StandardJMeterEngine.java:208) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:381) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_231]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
... 11 more
```

Though it is giving this exception but after some time chromedriver open chorme but it is not executing further script like browse the url, log in etc.

What will be the possible cause?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem . Problem is I have docker in my machine. while I was running my jmeter server on master, I saw that server is starting with Docker vEthernet IP. So I have disabled vEthernet(Docker NAT). Now it is working.